# SQL Server - Need to 'Pivot' a date range into separate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table of records that records consultants work. I need to take each row of data that includes a date range and transform the row into separate records in a new table. I have used one record as an example. See below (dates in UK format dd/mm/yyyy) :

**C_Name        Customer_Name   StartDate       EndDate**

Bob Jones   AcmeHealth      1/2/2018        5/2/2018

Transform into …

**Name      Customer_Name   WorkDate**

Bob Jones   AcmeHealth       1/2/2018
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth       2/2/2018
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth       3/2/2018
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth       4/2/2018
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth       5/2/2018

Any ideas how I can do this ?

Comment: If you find yourself saying you need to take `each row` and transform it, you're almost certainly going to be working with the `APPLY` operator or a cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a calendar or tally table, you can use CROSS APPLY in concert with an ad-hoc tally table.

**Example**

```
Select A.C_Name
      ,A.Customer_Name
      ,WorkDate = B.D
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,StartDate,EndDate)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),StartDate) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
C_Name      Customer_Name   WorkDate
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth      2018-02-01
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth      2018-02-02
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth      2018-02-03
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth      2018-02-04
Bob Jones   AcmeHealth      2018-02-05
```

If you really want the dates formated (which belongs in the presentation layer), you can make the following change:

```
...
,WorkDate = convert(varchar(10),B.D,101)
...
```

Comment: John, thanks very much for replying. Thats worked a treat. Much appreciated, MoonMoth

Comment: @MoonMoth Happy to help.